# android database cannot be filled and retrieved properly

Tags: android, sql, database

I am now working on putting in some built-in values to the database for later retrieval, and perform as follows. But it reports error that starting from id=102 the database cannot be written into during the process of `init_food_DB()` to perform `fill_food_DB()`, and maybe then further causing error when retrieving during the process of `Inflate_All_Food_Data`.

### Question:

In this app I before has created another database ("first_database"). This first database can be executed, written into, and retrieved properly.

Based on the success, I hence exactly copy from this first_database, and then just replace the value.length to be 248, and replace the content only.

Why the first database can be executed properly, but this food database stops filling in at id=102?

For reference, the ContentValues for first database is 63.

### MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_main); 

    init_food_DB();


    if(Food_dbHlp == null)
        Food_dbHlp = new Food_DataBaseHelper(this);
    food = Food_dbHlp.get_All_food_Data();  //LINE 221
    int i = food.size();        
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
    {
        Inflate_All_Food_Data(j);
    }   
}

private void init_food_DB()
{
    if(Food_dbHlp == null)
        Food_dbHlp = new Food_DataBaseHelper(this);
        Food_dbHlp.fill_food_DB();  
}
```

### Food_DataBaseHelper

```
public class Food_DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "food";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_food";
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = 
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                " id TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                " food_group TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                " food_name TEXT, " +
                " food_qty TEXT, " +
                " food_cal TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id)); ";
public static final String COL_id = "id";
public static final String COL_food_group = "food_group";
public static final String COL_food_name = "food_name";
public static final String COL_food_qty = "food_qty";
public static final String COL_food_cal = "food_cal";

public Food_DataBaseHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}


public void fill_food_DB() 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();      
    ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues[248];
    for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
        values[i] = new ContentValues();

    values[0].put("id", "001");
    values[0].put("food_group", "Snacks");
    values[0].put("food_name","Chestnuts");
    values[0].put("food_qty","100g");
    values[0].put("food_cal","170");
    values[1].put("id", "002");
    values[1].put("food_group", "Snacks");
    values[1].put("food_name","Brazil apricots");
    values[1].put("food_qty","100g");
    values[1].put("food_cal","619");
            ...
            ...
    values[247].put("id", "248");
    values[247].put("food_group", "Milk product");
    values[247].put("food_name","Crispy chocolate ice cream sticks");
    values[247].put("food_qty","1 cup");
    values[247].put("food_cal","372");

    for(ContentValues row : values)
    {
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, row);
    }   
    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<Food> get_All_food_Data()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {COL_id, COL_food_group, COL_food_name, COL_food_qty, COL_food_cal};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, COL_id); //LINE 1308
    ArrayList<Food> foods = new ArrayList<Food>();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String id = cursor.getString(0);
        String food_group = cursor.getString(1);
        String food_name = cursor.getString(2);
        String food_qty = cursor.getString(3);
        String food_cal = cursor.getString(4);          
        Food food = new Food(id, food_group, food_name, food_qty, food_cal);
        foods.add(food);            
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return foods;       
}
```

But reports error when id reaches 102

### Logcat reports as follows:

```
08-03 22:03:20.570: E/SQLiteLog(8105): (1) no such table: table_food
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105): Error inserting id=102 food_name=Tomato food_group=Fruits & vegetables food_qty=100g food_cal=14
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_food (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_food(id,food_name,food_group,food_qty,food_cal) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.abc.abc.Abc_Food_DataBaseHelper.fill_food_DB(Abc_Food_DataBaseHelper.java:1299)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.abc.abc.Food_MainActivity.init_food_DB(Food_MainActivity.java:262)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.abc.abc.Food_MainActivity.onCreate(Food_MainActivity.java:64)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteLog(8105): (1) no such table: table_food
08-03 22:03:20.615: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105): Error inserting id=103 food_name=Chinese water chestnut food_group=Fruits & vegetables food_qty=100g food_cal=68
 ...
 ...keep continue for every id from 102 to 248
 ...
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105): Error inserting id=248 food_name=Crispy chocolate ice cream sticks food_group=Milk product food_qty=1 cup food_cal=372
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_food (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_food(id,food_name,food_group,food_qty,food_cal) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.abc.abc.Abc_Food_DataBaseHelper.fill_food_DB(Abc_Food_DataBaseHelper.java:1299)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.abc.abc.Food_MainActivity.init_food_DB(Food_MainActivity.java:262)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.abc.abc.Food_MainActivity.onCreate(Food_MainActivity.java:64)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-03 22:03:21.245: E/SQLiteDatabase(8105):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)   
08-03 22:03:21.265: E/SQLiteLog(8105): (1) no such table: table_food
08-03 22:03:21.285: D/AndroidRuntime(8105): Shutting down VM
08-03 22:03:21.285: W/dalvikvm(8105): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c572a0)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.abc/com.abc.abc.Food_MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_food (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, food_group, food_name, food_qty, food_cal FROM table_food ORDER BY id
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_food (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, food_group, food_name, food_qty, food_cal FROM table_food ORDER BY id
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at com.abc.abc.Abc_Food_DataBaseHelper.get_All_food_Data(Abc_Food_DataBaseHelper.java:1308)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at com.abc.abc.Food_MainActivity.onCreate(Food_MainActivity.java:221)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
08-03 22:03:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(8105):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess one of two things.  Perhaps you have a permissions issue, and simply don't have the rights to create a table in the database (or are misnaming the database).

Or, the table might already exist.  If so, you could do:

```
 create table if not exists . . .
```

rather than:

```
create table . . .
```

To initialize the class, you might then want to remove any data in the table.  After creation you can do:

```
delete from . . .;
```

Or before the creation:

```
drop table if exists . . .;
```

Actually, dropping the table is a better approach.  If you decide to change the table structure, then you know it will be implemented.

Comment: permission issue? I have tried amend as "create table if not exists" but still fails...and the table should not have existed before I get start off the Activity for the first time, and the fill_DB action would only performed only once, as the user can amend the built-in data afterwards..... i do not understand why the first database can run properly using exactly the same codes...=(

Comment: the database_name for the first database is food, while this second one is also food. I discovered if i change this second one to food2, then everything is ok...why so?